# Firebase Development And Live Versions

Tags: angularjs, firebase, firebase-hosting

I've been searching all over for a solution to this one. I'm not sure what I'm missing. But from what I can see I'm able to create two firebase databases (Live and Development) and use them for each respectively. However, no matter what I've done, my locally served version still pulls from the live version. This is what I've done.

Created development project in firebase

Ran `firebase use --add` to add Development as an alias

Ran `firebase use` to confirm and got back the following:

```
default (live project-code)
development (development project-code)
```

Ran `firebase use development`

Ran `firebase serve`

Now, I would think if I load up localhost:5000 I would see just empty tables as my database in development is empty. Instead, I'm still seeing my live data.

Am I thinking this feature does more than it really does or am I just missing something?

I'm using Firebase for auth, database, storage, hosting and functions. This is all web based with AngularJs.

**UPDATE**

So it appears I've found the issue. In my `app.js` file I am defining the database url and I also have the firebase config block.

```
.constant('FirebaseDatabaseUrl', 'LiveProjectUrl')

.config(function($firebaseRefProvider, FirebaseDatabaseUrl, $routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
    var config = {
        apiKey: "",
        authDomain: "",
        databaseURL: "",
        projectId: "",
        storageBucket: "",
        messagingSenderId: ""
    };
    firebase.initializeApp(config);

})
```

How are these two pieces (the console code and hard code) supposed to work together? Or do I not need this `app.js` code? If I just set a variable for development = true during development, how would I have it change when I wanted to upload to live?

**UPDATE 2**

I created a simple if else statement in my config block with a variable but I feel like there should be a better way to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firebase Hosting recently added the ability to [auto-configure the Firebase SDKs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/reserved-urls#sdk_auto-configuration) by using a special script includes:

```
<script src="/__/firebase/4.1.3/firebase-app.js"></script>
<script src="/__/firebase/4.1.3/firebase-auth.js"></script>
<script src="/__/firebase/4.1.3/firebase-storage.js"></script>
<!-- load Firebase SDK before loading this file -->
<script src="/__/firebase/init.js"></script>
```

This should let your site configure correctly without having to apply any logic.

Comment: Would this be able to help me in supplying the cloud function base url for the different projects?

Comment: @MitchEvans Not really.  If you want to associate the current hosting site with its Cloud Functions backend, consider routing calls from the site to the backend using rewrite rules so that you don't have to care about the backend hostname. https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/functions